# Both PDF and Word downloads are ASCII-8bit instead of UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, prawn

I am building a ruby on rails app.
Though the data is stored as UTF-8 in the database, while exporting to Word/PDF, they are ASCII-8bit encoded.

Where should I make the change?

Comment: _"Where should I make the change?"_ – `lib/export.rb`, line 23.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist ;-) Could you show some code, please? How do you generate the PDF?

Comment: I use the prawn gem

Comment: I already noticed the `prawn` tag. Please show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

in config/application.rb. Hope this solves your problem.